# Increase session lifetime in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session-cookies, php-7, symfony-3.4

I have this code in `framework.yaml` :

```
session:
    handler_id: ~
    cookie_lifetime: 43200
    gc_maxlifetime: 43200
```

I want the session to be alive about 12 hours, but after some minutes the session expire. What else modification should I do ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, your current configuration make PHP save session files inside `/var/lib/php/sessions` and this directory always checked and PID inside it removed by a cron job configured in `php.ini` via `gc_maxlifetime`.

To fixed this issue you have to override the session handler and make Symfony handle the session using  `handler_id` and `save_path` option as the following:

```
framework:
        session:
            handler_id: session.handler.native_file
            save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
            cookie_lifetime: 43200
            gc_maxlifetime: 43200
```